# How to fix those kind of issues after sculpting?

Tags: sculpting, smooth

I'm entirely new to Blender, and I took a break day from courses to practice out few things.

I sculpted a cat head starting from a sphere. I continuously used the subdivision surface when needed, the smooth modifier, and used the "grab" tool.

This was the result:

[image]

While grabbing, I tried to smooth it out using the "Shift" modifier key. I also tried the "smooth" modifier but have had no results.

Your help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: If you don't succeed with any brush, maybe remesh?